# String concatenation based of column length

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2016

i have telephone number like this in one table:

```
 ID   Telephone     extention
------------------------------
1    9986323422     4            
2    9992108        2222         
3    9962718        241
```

Final result wanted is number of digit in extention will be taken and replace the end digit/(s) of "Telephone" column.

want my result to be:

```
   ID   Telephone     extention   result
-----------------------------------------
1    9986323422     4           9986323424 
2    9992108        2222        9992222 
3    9962718        241         9962241
```

I have 100k records like this. What is the best and quick way to achieve this? Thanks.

Comment: What is the datatype of Telephone and Extension columns.?

Answer (score 1):

This may be a little too cute<sup>1</sup> but is an alternative to the `STUFF` approaches:

```
SELECT ID,Telephone,Extension,
   SUBSTRING(Telephone,1-LEN(Extension),LEN(Telephone)) + Extension as Result
```

It works because negative arguments to the *start* parameter for [`SUBSTRING`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/substring-transact-sql) allow you to truncate the end of the string by those amounts.

---

<sup>1</sup>It avoid repetitive calls to `LEN()`, but the optimizer should be able to avoid duplication anyway and avoids having to reverse the entire string, but this does come at a readability cost.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `STUFF()` together with some calculations with `LEN()`

```
DECLARE  @dummyTable TABLE(ID INT,Telephone VARCHAR(100), extention VARCHAR(100));
INSERT INTO @dummyTable VALUES
 (1,'9986323422','4')            
,(2,'9992108','2222')        
,(3,'9962718','241');

SELECT *
      ,STUFF(t.Telephone,LEN(t.Telephone)-LEN(t.extention)+1,LEN(t.extention),t.extention) AS result
FROM @dummyTable AS t;
```

You might have to add some validations to avoid errors (e.g. length of extension should be smaller than of phone number)

Answer (score 0):

In similar way use `reverse()` function with `stuff()` function to replace ends digits of Telephone value with extention value

```
select *, reverse(stuff(reverse(Telephone), 1, len(extention), reverse(extention))) 
from table
```